# Make an email that is within a block of text linkable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an email address contained in a WordPress site description. I would like to make it a link.

Here is the code:

```
function maker_site_description() {
    $class = 'site-description';
    if ( ! get_theme_mod( 'display_blogdescription', true ) ) {
        $class .= ' screen-reader-text';
    }
    printf( '<p class="%s">%s</p>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) );
}
endif;
```

How can I make it detect the email address inside, and make it link to a mailto?

Comment: You mean the email is embedded in the description text? There is more text than just the email? For example *"Welcome to my site! To contact me, email me at me@me.com.  Have Fun!"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code, an email would get stripped out anyway (due to the [esc_html](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html)), so we have to take that out.

Then, before we pass the string into your `printf`, we have to first parse it using a regular express to find the e-mail, and replace it with a link.

See the modified function below:

```
function maker_site_description() {
    $class = 'site-description';
    if ( ! get_theme_mod( 'display_blogdescription', true ) ) {
        $class .= ' screen-reader-text';
    }

    // First we have to load the description into a variable
    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );

    // This is a regular express that will find email addresses
    $pattern = '/[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i';

    // Search the description for emails, and assign to $matches variable
    preg_match( $pattern, $description, $matches );

    // Only make changes if a match has been found
    if ( ! empty( $matches[0] ) ) {
       $email = $matches[0];
       // Build the "mailto" link
       $link = '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';

       // Replace the email with the link in the description
       $description = str_ireplace( $email, $link, $description );
    }

    // NOW we can print, but we have to remove the esc_html
    printf( '<p class="%s">%s</p>', esc_attr( $class ), $description );
}
```